# How to correctly show Buttons in a LinearLayout inside a HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android, layout, uibutton, android-linearlayout

I added a HorizontalScrollView with a LinearLayout, Buttons are added programmatically in order to show a category selector.

This is the result in an emulator with API 23, 1080x1920 xxhdpi:

[image: Emulator with API 23 1080x1920 xxhdpi]

This is how it looks in my Android phone with API 22:

[image: This is how it looks in my Android phone with Api 22:]

This is my xml code:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hsvClosetFilter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rlt"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewCategoryNames"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

And I'm adding buttons programatically like this:

```
private void buildCategoryScroll() {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(230, 80);
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 10, 30, 10);

        for (int i=0; i<categoryNames.size(); i++) {
            final Button btCategory = new Button(getActivity());
            btCategory.setText(categoryNames.get(i));
            btCategory.setTextSize(16f);
            btCategory.setAllCaps(false);
            btCategory.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary));
            btCategory.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.white));
            btCategory.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            btCategory.setTag(i);
            viewCategoryNames.addView(btCategory);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout viewCategoryNames;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        viewCategoryNames = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewCategoryNames);
        buildCategoryScroll();

    }

    private void buildCategoryScroll() {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 10, 30, 10);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
            final Button btCategory = new Button(MainActivity.this);
            btCategory.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            btCategory.setTextSize(16f);
            btCategory.setAllCaps(false);
            btCategory.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
            btCategory.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.black));
            btCategory.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            btCategory.setTag(i);
            viewCategoryNames.addView(btCategory);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/hsvClosetFilter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlt"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    tools:context="com.example.rohantaneja.horizontalscrollview.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewCategoryNames"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Step 1:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/viewCategoryNames"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Step 2:

```
private void buildCategoryScroll() {
for (int i=0; i<categoryNames.size(); i++) { 
final Button btCategory = new Button(getActivity());
btCategory.setText(categoryNames.get(i)); 
btCategory.setTextSize(16f); 
btCategory.setAllCaps(false);
btCategory.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary)); 
btCategory.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.white));
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(230, 80); 
layoutParams.setMargins(0, 10, 30, 10);
btCategory.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); 
btCategory.setTag(i); 
viewCategoryNames.addView(btCategory); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work.. I got the same result in emulator